# How can I get the GUID from a PDB file?

Tags: debugging, guid, pdb-files, dia-sdk

Does anyone know how to get the GUID from a PDB file?

I'm using Microsoft's Debug Interface Access SDK

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0756hat.aspx

and getting E_PDB_INVALID_SIG when passing in the GUID i expect when trying to load the PDB.

I'd just like to know the GUID of the PDB so I can be certain that it's mismatching and not just a PDB that's perhaps corrupted somehow.

Is there a tool that can do this?  I've tried dia2dump and dumpbin, but with no joy...

Many thanks,

thoughton.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [Code Project tool called PDB Inspector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/bugs/PdbParser.aspx) that should be able to help you. Or if you need to do this programatically essentially you call:

```
IDiaDataSource::LoadDataFromPdb
IDiaDataSource::openSession
IDiaSession::get_global_scope
IDiaSymbol::get_guid
```

Comment: FYI, this link is dead

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37883/Symbols-File-Locator

Answer (score 2):

I would use the dbghelp symbol APIs.  If all you want is information about the PDB, you can use [chkmatch on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210205095232/https://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html), or heck, just load the dll/exe into WinDbg and use `!sym noisy`, `!lmi` or `!chksym`.

Fixing the PDB to match is a different story!  chkmatch can do some of the work, but cannot make age differences match, it only can do timestamps and GUID signatures.

Answer (score 2):

an [introduction](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37883/Symbols-File-Locator) to DIA and its relation to DbgHelp along with a C++ sample. Which is basically the article I wrote after the one mentioned by Paul Arnold.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37883/Symbols-File-Locator