# Extracting guid from pdb file

Tags: debugging, guid, debug-symbols, pdb-files, bsod

I need to parse some BSOD crash files but I have a terrible mess with the symbols. I have tons of pdb files, under folders so that the folder names are the pdb files GUIDs, but I believe that the files are in mess.

All I need to do is find a way to extract the GUID from the pdb file.
I managed to find [this tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37456/How-To-Inspect-the-Content-of-a-Program-Database-P). But unfortunately I have errors and can't make it work.

From what managed to understand, there's a way to enter the cmd of visual-basic and there is a command called `dumpbin`, that should return the GUID if running it with the flag `/HEADERS` as it mentioned [here](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know).

But once again I failed to do so and whenever I try I get the following warning:

> Dump of file Netwsw04.pdb
>
> Netwsw04.pdb : warning LNK4048: Invalid format file; ignored

Comment: Indeed i mean blue screen of death
s.t = so that

Comment: OK, thanks. Unless abbreviations are in common use, they are best avoided. I've never heard of `s.t.` as an acronym before, and I'm a native English speaker.

Comment: Sorry :D its from my degree, mathematical proofs use s.t all the time

Comment: OK, I didn't know that! Thanks. Not a mathematician `:-)`.

Answer (score 3):

Dumpbin works for .exe files and .dll files, but not .pdb files. You need to use the Debug Interface Access SDK for that. Check out this question for more info.
[How can I get the GUID from a PDB file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517791/how-can-i-get-the-guid-from-a-pdb-file)